# Validation Error upon submit the summernote text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a summernote in my textarea, in my form, I used the JQuery validation to submit my form. The summernote text area is not required. However the validation still validates my summernote and throws me the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
```

Ok, now the problem comes, when I put some simple value like ' 12345' the summernote is validated without any problem, however, when I put some complex code like copy and paste from somewhere else, it gives me the above error.
[image: a busy cat]

Then I tried to put the ignore when I do the validation, however it did not work, may I know how I can solve this?

My code:

```
                    $('#' + form_id).validate({ ignore: ".note-editable.panel-body"});
                    if ($('#' + form_id).valid()) {
                        $('#' + form_id).submit();
                    }


        $('.summernote').summernote({ height: 500 });


                    $('#' + form_id).validate({ ignore: ".note-editable.panel-body"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fixed it by using below code

```
                $('#' + form_id).validate({ ignore: ".note-editor *"});
```